# Angular Material Checkbox and Tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I used Angular material which are "Mat-Checkbox and Mat-Tab". I would like to keep the checked status for checkbox but when I change the tab it is going to be unchecked all. Is there any way to keep the checkbox status even if I change to other tab?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post your source code or upload to Stackblitz so that we can help you

Comment: [Mycode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)

Here is my code but it is not working in StackBlitz. Please just see the code. I used html's checkbox because of the performance. I need to display a thousand item so it is very slow when I use "mat-checkbox".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked">
    I'm a checkbox
  </mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: I tried that but I could not use mat-checkbox because of the performance. I need to display a thousand of item and it was very slow to display when I use it. Is there any way for html's checkbox?

Comment: I've used to use <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime" ng-checked="true">
      Open only one at a time
    </label> (like an example) in angularjs, maybe with this you can do it, try with a similar directive on angular.